# Активация флажка

Tags: html, javascript

У меня есть 2 поля с флажками
Мне нужно, чтобы когда я снимаю галочку с одного, и при условии, если другой флажок не активирован, то активировать его.
В общем, мне нужно, чтобы не оставалось пустых флажков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В некоторой ситуации достаточно такого:

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch1" onchange="if ( !this.checked ) this.nextElementSibling.checked = true;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" onchange="if ( !this.checked ) this.previousElementSibling.checked = true;">
</div>
```

P.S: `checkbox`'ы должны идти подряд

2. Можно так:

```js
function recheck(el, id) {
  if (!el.checked) document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="ch1" id="ch1" onchange="recheck( this, 'ch2' );">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch2" id="ch2" onchange="recheck( this, 'ch1' );">
```

3. Чтобы не генерировать лишних событий:

```js
function recheck(el, id) {
  if (!el.checked) {
    var el2 = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!el2.checked) el2.checked = true;
  }
}
```